# How to remove the index after transposing a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a pandas dataframe in python that looks like the following:

[image]

I used the following code to transpose my dataframe:

```
groupedt = grouped.transpose()
groupedt.head()
```

And this is what the resulting dataframe looks like:

[image]

Is there a way for me to remove the index range above each column and then change the "StateName" column name to "Date"?

Comment: Does `grouped.set_index('StateName').T` help?

Comment: yes, that helped, thank you! @enke